# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#

i have this code:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
foreach (DataRow dataR in prenume.Rows)
{
    foreach (var item in dataR.ItemArray)
    {
        if (item.Equals("  ")) continue;
        list.Add(item);
        if (input_string.Equals(item.ToString()) && list.Count > 0 )
        {
            label_hello.Text = "Hello, " + list[2];
        }
    }
}
```

When i'm trying to clear the text showed , i get an error which says:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less  than the size
>   of the collection.

Later edit:

```
        Solution found!I was too tired ... sorry for the question!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you start off with an empty list, and then after adding a single item, you might execute (if `input_string` equals the first item in the first item array):

```
label_hello.Text = "Hello, " + list[2];
```

That's trying to access the *third* item in the list. It will fail when there's only one item. Why did you pick `2` here?

(As an aside, why are you using `ArrayList`? The generic `List<T>` type is preferred.)

It's not clear what you're *trying* to achieve - if you can give us more context, we have a better chance of helping you.

EDIT: From the comments, it looks like this should be

```
label_hello.Text = "Hello, " + dataR[2];
```

However, I suspect the loops are still not right... why would you want to iterate over *every* value in the table, rather than (say) in just one column?

Comment: Because that's the element from the arraylist which i want to write.

Comment: @EmilDumbazu: But the list doesn't *have* three elements - the first time you get to this statement, the list will only have a single element. So how can the *third* element be the one you want?

Comment: The code executes when a text from textbox is changed. And the list has as many elements as characters....

Comment: @EmilDumbazu: No it doesn't - look carefully at your code... you create a new list (so it's empty) and the if the input string is equal to the first item in the item array, it will go into that block and execute the failing statement when the list only has one element. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, but that's why it's failing.

Comment: Asking a guy who doesn't know how to use arrays and indexers why you didn't use `Generics` is like asking me, hmmm, a lot of things...

Comment: Perhaps you meant do do: `dataR.ItemArray[2]` instead at that point?

Comment: I have a Datatable which contains rows like (id,name,password). What i want to do is that when the user has entered his password , a label message like "Hello "+name should be displayed.

Comment: @EmilDumbazu: So why are you using `list[2]`? Did you mean `dataR[2]`?

Comment: Yeah , thank you ! I'm too tired and now i realize how stupid i was. Sorry guys !

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse it will give an error.

```
label_hello.Text = "Hello, " + list[2];
```

is wrong. 
You have only one element list[0] at that stage.

Comment: If it works exactly how you want it to work, why are you asking? If you *want* that exception, why are you asking about it?

Comment: If you want the second element, get your list[2] outside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

you're getting your error on the following line

```
label_hello.Text = "Hello, " + list[2];
```

The reason why you're getting that error is because there is no list[2]

Now, I can't tell exactly what you're trying to do, but I have a sneaky suspicion that you intend 'item' to be a string of some sort, and you want to access the third character in that string.

Even then, keep in mind that sometimes the user might try to input a string that is not 3 or more characters in length.

If you can give more details about what you're trying to do,  we can help you further.